# select query using leftjoin doesnt work

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I want to left join this query but it does not seem to work

```
 select *,(SELECT datediff(t1.expirydate,CURDATE())as daysleft
 from tbl1 t1,
 left join tbl2 t2  on (t1.mid=t2.mid and t1.pid=t2.pid and t1.uid=3)
```

you have an error in your SQL syntax;

```
right syntax to use near 'left join tbl2 t2  on (t1.mid=t2.mid and t1.pid=t2.p' at line 3
```

Please let me know where am i wrong

here am joining 3 table but doesnt work

```
 SELECT t1.*, t2.*,t3.* datediff(t1.expirydate, CURDATE()) AS daysleft FROM tbl1 t1 left join  
  tbl2 t2 on t1.mid = t2.mid and t1.pid = t2.pid left join tbl3 t3 on t3.pid = t2.pid where t1.uid=3
```

for knw 3 table but the i get syntax error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't put a comma between joins.

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.*, datediff(fsp.expirydate, CURDATE()) AS daysleft
FROM tbl1 t1
left join tbl2 t2 on t1.mid = t2.mid and t1.pid = t2.pid
cross join fsp
where t1.uid = 3
```

You also shouldn't put the `t1.uid = 3` condition in the `ON` clause. `ON` should only contain conditions that relate the two tables, and in the case of `LEFT JOIN` it can also include conditions on the table you're joining with (`t2` in this case).

Comment: here am joining 3 table but doesnt work SELECT t1.*, t2.*,t3.* datediff(t1.expirydate, CURDATE()) AS daysleft
FROM tbl1 t1
left join tbl2 t2 on t1.mid = t2.mid and t1.pid = t2.pid  left join tbl3 t3 on  t3.pid = t2.pid  where t1.uid=3 .......... for knw 3 table  but the i get syntax error

Comment: Are you asking something in that comment?

Comment: ya have upadte in my comment

Comment: Can you make a sqlfiddle?

Comment: You're missing the comma after `t3.*`.

Answer (score 1):

No comma after "t1" on line 2.

Also I don't think you can do "*," on line 1, you need to either do "SELECT *" or "SELECT column, column2"

Answer (score 1):

You have Used **Comma (,)** before **Left Join** It's not correct Synatx

Try this

```
 select t1.*,(SELECT datediff(fsp.expirydate,CURDATE())as daysleft
 from tbl1 t1
 left join tbl2 t2  on (t1.mid=t2.mid and t1.pid=t2.pid and t1.uid=3)
```

## [Join Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)